# Cannot implicitly convert type to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to populate a viewmodel with a DateTime property, and also a list of categories.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class TourCategoryVM
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<TourCategoryList> TourCategoryList { get; set; }
}

public class TourCategoryList
{
    public int TourCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string TourType { get; set; }
}
```

Domain model:

```
public class TourCategory
{
    public int TourCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string TourType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tour> Tour { get; set; }
}
```

I thought I could populate it easily with this code:

```
        var viewModel = new TourCategoryVM();
        viewModel.TourCategoryList = db.TourCategories();
```

However, I'm getting the error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<tb.Models.TourCategory>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<tb.Models.ViewModels.TourCategoryList>`

Is it my ViewModel that's wrong?

Comment: try adding a .tolist() to your db.tourcategories()

Comment: Thanks Matt - I tried that but got: Non-invocable member 'tb.Models.tbContext.TourCategories' cannot be used like a method

Comment: In the future be use to use backticks " ` " to surround text that includes a `<SomeClass>` that is not in a code block, the website will strip them out if you don't thinking they are html tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `db.TourCategories()` method does not return a collection of `TourCategoryList`, so you'll have to do a little more work to convert whatever class `TourCategories()` returns into a `TourCategoryList`, using the LINQ `Select()` method.

```
viewModel.TourCategoryList = db.TourCategories()
                               .Select(tc => new TourCategoryList
                                             {
                                                 TourCategoryId = tc.TourCategoryId,
                                                 TourType = tc.TourType
                                             })
                               .ToList();
```

I'm assuming that `TourCategories()` returns a collection of `TourCategory`.

---

If I could make one other suggestion, you might want to rename `TourCategoryList`. I know you're trying to differentiate it from the other `TourCategory` class, but someone looking at your code might assume (at first glance) that `List<TourCategoryList>` is a list of lists, just from the name.

Comment: `TourCategoryModel` is the conventional choice for a different class name.

Comment: Thanks Grant - I did that, and also renamed TourCategoryList to TourCategoryModel - but now have another error: The entity or complex type 'tb.Models.TourCategoryModel' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.  So I added .ToList() after dbTourCategories() and it worked!  Thanks a lot for your help.  Mark